# Java sorting - all upper case first

Tags: java, arrays, collections, comparator, comparable

I wanted to sort items like these (all upper case sorted first):

```
A
B
C
D
a
b
c
d
```

How to do using collections sort? Let's say my object is Account and accountName is the field I wanted sorted that way

thanks

Comment: based on ascii, A is coming before a, so as long as you sort it ascendingly, it will be sorted as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement Comparable interface in your account class and override compareTo() method.

```
class Account implements Comparable{

    public String accountName;

    public Account(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
        this.accountName = accountName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account [accountName=" + accountName + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        Account accObj = (Account) obj;

        return this.accountName.compareTo(accObj.accountName);
    }

}
```

now Collections.sort() will return you desired result.

```
List<Account> accList= new ArrayList<Account>();
accList.add(new Account("B"));
accList.add(new Account("c"));
accList.add(new Account("A"));

accList.add(new Account("C"));
accList.add(new Account("a"));
accList.add(new Account("b"));

Collections.sort(accList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying something to find solution for this?
You always can able to write custom Comparator or using one of the existing

```
//List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
Set<Account> sorted = accounts.stream().sorted(((o1, o2) -> o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()))).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

or

```
Set<Account> sorted = accounts.stream().sorted(((o1, o2) -> {
   //do whatever you want with your custom comparator logic
})).collect(Collectors.toList());
```